# Elegant String Method (How to be more Pythonic)

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to do a string replace, to remove all of the special and unsafe characters used in a search phrase, to something suitable to be inserted into a Google URL.

I could use multiple instances of .replace or re.sub, but that seems inefficient. Is there a faster or more Pythonic way of doing this? I'm thinking I'm moving beyond beginner and into intermediate lately, because of all my attempts at making my code cleaner and more efficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of doing the replacement yourself, I would suggest using [`urllib.quote()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote), which returns a URL-safe string by converting special characters to `%xx` escapes.

The benefit here is that you can easily obtain the original string from your URL safe version using [`urllib.unquote()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote) (and you don't need to write the code yourself!).

Comment: Boom. You sir, are the victor.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is [`string.translate`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.translate)

e.g.

```
>>> string.translate('ds..ad$ds#a', None, '.,@#$')
'dsaddsa'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is the use of `re.sub`, see the [regex documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) for more details.

As an example:

```
# re.sub(pattern, replacement, target_string)
>>> re.sub("@|#|\$", "" , 'asdf@#$asdf')
'asdfasdf'
```

Note that you can specify the signs you want to replace by an empty string, meaning you can add/remove special characters. It does however require you to have some knowledge of regex patterns.